# How to get google form data at onFormSubmit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I want to send some google form data to outside API using UrlFetchApp.fetch when the google form is submitted but there is no form data in event data.

1. My script is here

   ```
    function onFormSubmit(e) {
        Logger.log(JSON.stringfy(e))

        UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.server.com/result', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            payload: JSON.stringify({
              answer1 : e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse(),
              answer2 : e.response.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse()
            }),
        })
    }
   ```
2. I add trigger to google form

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnd1L.png)

3. When google form is submitted, the function, onFormSubmit is called correctly but e has no response data like below log.

   ```
    {"authMode":"FULL","response":{},"source":{},"triggerUid":"16459009"}
   ```

My question is

1. Why the event of onFormSubmit doesn't have any response data(=form data)?
2. Is there something to do more (like install other trigger?)
3. What should I do for correct action?

Comment: e.values is an array values for the current row being submits and e.namedValues is an object with properties for each columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `onFormSubmit` trigger for a script container-bound to a Google Form and you think that your log shows that the script is not collecting any form response data.

**Your log results do NOT mean that no response data was collected.**

The Event Objects `response` contains a `FormResponse` object, representing the user's response to the form as a whole.

To see your form response data, add the following after your "stringify" line:

---

```
let responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
for (i = 0; i<responses.length ; i++){
  Logger.log(responses[i].getResponse())
}
```

---

**UrlFetchApp.fetch - PayLoad**

Suggested modification

**From**

```
payload: JSON.stringify({
           answer1 : e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse(),
           answer2 : e.response.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse()
         }),
```

**To**

```
payload: answer1 : e.response.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse(),
         answer2 : e.response.getItemResponses()[1].getResponse()
        ,
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer.

I tried as you mentioned but I got error. I'm not sure what is wrong.

Log : 
TypeError : Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading 'response')
onFormSubmit @ testResult.gs:2

Code  :
`function onFormSubmit(e) {
    let responses = e.response.getItemResponses();
    for (i = 0; i<responses.length ; i++){
         Logger.log(responses[i].getResponse())
    }
}`

Comment: `Cannot read properties of undefined ( reading 'response') onFormSubmit` - means the parameter e is undefined which means this function did not execute via the trigger. Don't try to execute it manually from the editor. Please confirm: 1) your script is bound to your Google Form, AND 2) you have an installable trigger for 'onFormSubmit' AND 3) you created a form submission in order to test the script.

Comment: My answer is
1), 3) absolutely!
2) not sure that's why I asked what to do more like install trigger as question no.2. Actually I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: `I add trigger to google form` The snapshot that you included shows that you added the trigger - there should be nothing more to do. BUT because of the error, you should double-check by 1) checking the Script Editor > Triggers Tab and confirm that the trigger is installed, and 2) checking the Script Editor, Executions Log and confirm that the script has been running.

Comment: I inserted `Logger.log('executing onFormSubmit')` at line 1 then I got the exact log at execution log of script editor.

Comment: `I got the exact log at execution log of script editor.` Which means that the trigger is working!! Would you please provide a snapshot of the first few questions in your form.

Comment: Please see the image line : [source](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Dqg0E8byCN-OZ2KwUq0gAvtzRqCkwLl-/view?usp=share_link)
 / [trigger pannel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/197c9-RS_aaJu-1zFfqRL-SDYexsFTCWO/view?usp=share_link) / 
[result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TLa8loAEcSCw9eSJlaFVnsxiksVv3q4_/view?usp=share_link)

Now it looks working well. I'm not sure what is changed from one hour age.